# PHP Global Variable Scope

Tags: php

I have a helper file that contains quite a few functions, but no "main" function. Each of these helper functions requires a database connection. To improve code maintainability, I'd like to put the variable that holds the database connection in a global state (outside of any of the functions) such that each function has visibility to it and can use it in their mysql calls. Here is what I mean:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$connection = $path . '/scripts/connection.php';
include ($connection); // this initializes the variable '$link'

function getLocation ($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM Locations WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if (!$result) { return -1; }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    mysqli_close($link);
    return $row['name'];
}

function getGroupID($group_id) {
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM Groups WHERE group='$group_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if (!$result) { return -1; }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    mysqli_close($link);
    return $row['id'];
}

// and many other similar functions
```

I'd rather not put those three global lines inside of each function since then I have to repeat code over and over, but this method has no global scope. I could probably look into passing the `$link` variable in as an argument, but that would require refactoring a LOT of function calls. I know that some frown on global variables like this, but in this case it is my simplest resolution.

As an aside, if I replace the three global lines with this:
`include '../scripts/connection.php'`
my code works fine, but then I lose some of the relative referencing flexibility. I don't understand why the code that I post here operates differently.

Is there a way that I can declare this `$connection` variable globally?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you not put `global` of the variable where you define it now?

Comment: @putvande Putting global at the definition site doesn't help, you have to put it in the functions that use the variable.

Comment: Regarding the difference between the absolute and relative paths, have you echo'ed out `$connection` to see if it's the path that you're expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put:

```
global $link;
```

at the beginning of each function.

Another way to do this is to define a function or class that opens the connection and returns the link. The connection can be a static variable in the function; if it's already set it doesn't reopen the connection:

```
function get_db_conn () {
    static $link;

    if ($link) {
        return $link;
    }
    $link = mysqli_connect(...);
    return $link;
}
```

Then all your other functions can start with:

```
$link = get_db_conn();
```

Comment: Obsessive objection to global variables I suspect.

Comment: Some answers that suggest using global get up voted, accepted, and praised. Other times down voted, "don't do that" and deleted

Comment: Thanks. `global $link` didn't work, but the function did. That's what I'll go with. And then I don't violate anybody's belief about global variables! :D

Comment: I don't understand why `global $link` didn't work. Are you opening the connection in a function in the include file? If so, you would need the `global` statement in that function as well.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your functions, use:

`global $connection`

This will pull the variable from the global scope into your function.

Alternatively, you could look into an ORM -- My personal favorite is IDIORM, but Doctrine and Propel are also good ones.